# After a Git pull, files are shown as deleted

Tags: git, macos, github, bitbucket

This is weird...

After I do a git pull of branch of my repository and do git status, I get this:

```
On branch dev
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/dev'.
Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    deleted:    server/api/accounts/BankProvider/responses/wResponses.js
    deleted:    server/api/accounts/BankProvider/index.js
    deleted:    server/api/accounts/BankProvider/models/BorderlessModel.js
    deleted:    server/api/accounts/BankProvider/models/UserRegistrationModel.js
    deleted:    server/api/accounts/BankProvider/syeUtils.js
    deleted:    server/api/accounts/Transaction/TransactionResponses.js
    deleted:    server/api/accounts/models/borderModelJoi.js

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

After this, I do a:

```
git checkout .
```

To remove all those changes (that I didn't do), and everything is fine, but if I swith to another branch, any branch, then those changes come back again.
The complete process is the following:

```
➜  ms-accounts git:(dev) ✗ git status
On branch dev
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/dev'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        deleted:    server/api/accounts/BankProvider/responses/wResponses.js
        deleted:    server/api/accounts/BankProvider/index.js
        deleted:    server/api/accounts/BankProvider/models/BorderlessModel.js
        deleted:    server/api/accounts/BankProvider/models/UserRegistrationModel.js
        deleted:    server/api/accounts/BankProviderUtils.js
        deleted:    server/api/accounts/Transaction/TransactionResponses.js
        deleted:    server/api/accounts/models/borderModelJoi.js

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
➜  ms-accounts git:(dev) ✗ git checkout .
➜  ms-accounts git:(dev) git status
On branch dev
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/dev'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean
➜  ms-accounts git:(dev) git checkout qa && git checkout dev
Switched to branch 'qa'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/qa'.
Switched to branch 'dev'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/dev'.
➜  ms-accounts git:(dev) ✗ git status
On branch dev
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/dev'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        deleted:    server/api/accounts/BankProvider/responses/wResponses.js
        deleted:    server/api/accounts/BankProvider/index.js
        deleted:    server/api/accounts/BankProvider/models/BorderlessModel.js
        deleted:    server/api/accounts/BankProvider/models/UserRegistrationModel.js
        deleted:    server/api/accounts/BankProvider/Utils.js
        deleted:    server/api/accounts/Transaction/TransactionResponses.js
        deleted:    server/api/accounts/models/borderModelJoi.js

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I believe there's an issue with the commit, because if we do this in other computer, it behaves the same way.

How can I remove those changed files for good? and upload them to the repo.

Comment: What is the `X` you've put before some of your git commands?  Initially I assumed it was part of your prompt, but since it's not there on all lines...?

Comment: Could be a case folding issue, if you do a `git ls-files`, do you see multiple instances of at least one of the files that looks to be deleted, just with different casing? What I mean is that for instance you would see both `index.js` and `Index.js` (upper-case I vs. lower-case i).

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger it's part of the terminal shell that I'm using... It's called zsh, and it marks an X whenever there are changes in the git repo... It's visual,

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen If I do a `git ls-files` I get only one instance of the file, with the same casing :/
This feels weirder everytime

Comment: Hmm... well, I don't believe there's anything wrong with the commit per se, because if there were then I can't see how `git checkout .` would fix it. Don't really have a theory yet, but for the sake of enumerating variables: are there submodules in the repo? Anything in .git/hooks? Any active git aliases in place?  Any .gitattributes files anywhere in the repo?  Content of .gitignore (not that it should matter)?

Comment: No submodules.
This is in .git/hooks: ```➜  .git git:(dev) ls hooks/
applypatch-msg.sample     post-update.sample        pre-commit.sample         pre-rebase.sample         prepare-commit-msg.sample
commit-msg.sample         pre-applypatch.sample     pre-push.sample           pre-receive.sample        update.sample``` No aliases, and I can't seem to find any .gitattributes

Comment: Sorry @MarkAdelsberger .gitignore has this:
# Mac
.DS_Store

# Win
Thumbs.db
ehthumbs.db

#IntelliJ
.idea

#Auto-generated
coverage
docs
documentation
node_modules
plato-reports
reports